# Require members in interface

Tags: typescript, inheritance, interface

I'm using interfaces in a distinctly non-interfacey way.

I have a program that has different types of module, each represented by a string - for the sake of argument let's call them `"text"` and `"image"`.

Each of these module types is related to several data structures, let's call them `document` and `transient`.  So for each of `text` and `image` there is a `document` data interface, and a `transient` data interface.

I form relationships between these types and data structures using weird sort of middle-ware interfaces:

```
type ModuleType = "image" | "text";

interface TextDocumentData { /* ... */}
interface ImageDocumentData { /* ... */}

interface DocumentDataMap {
    "image": ImageDocumentData;
    "text": TextDocumentData;
}

interface TextTransientData { /* ... */}
interface ImageTransientData { /* ... */}

interface TransientDataMap {
    "image": ImageTransientData;
    "text": TextTransientData;
}
```

Which I then use in functions like so:

```
interface AllData<T extends ModuleType> {
    doc: DocumentDataMap[T];
    trn: TransientDataMap[T];
}

function getAllData<T extends ModuleType>(moduleType: T): AllData<T> { /* ... */ }
```

This will make `getAllData("text").doc;` return an object of type `TextDocumentData`.

This all works fine (even if it is hard to read).  What I'd like to do now is make sure that if a new module type is added (let's call it `table`) `tsc` errors out at compile time until I've added a `"table"` entry to `DocumentDataMap` and `TransientDataMap`.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
type ModuleType = "image" | "text" | "table";
type DocumentData = TextDocumentData | ImageDocumentData | TableDocumentData;
type TransientData = TextTransientData | ImageTransientData;

type ModuleTypeMap<T> = {[m in ModuleType]: T};

interface TextDocumentData { /* ... */}
interface ImageDocumentData { /* ... */}
interface TableDocumentData { /* ... */}

interface DocumentDataMap extends ModuleTypeMap<DocumentData> {
    "image": ImageDocumentData;
    "text": TextDocumentData;
    "table": TableDocumentData;
}

interface TextTransientData { /* ... */}
interface ImageTransientData { /* ... */}

// This should cause an error (there's no entry for tables!)
interface TransientDataMap extends ModuleTypeMap<TransientData> {
    "image": ImageTransientData;
    "text": TextTransientData;
}
```

The type `ModuleTypeMap` enforces an object with every possible `ModuleType` as keys, and type T as values.  `DocumentDataMap` and `TransientDataMap` inherit from this.  If I were actually using these interfaces on real objects, this would work fine, but since they're only used to create a relationship between strings and data types, *extending* `ModuleTypeMap` doesn't do anything.

**Is there a way to make sure that interfaces have certain members?**  Is there a better way to achieve relationships between strings and data types/interfaces?  I feel like I'm pretty far outside of the intended use of interfaces in TypeScript at this point...

Comment: You will get an error in `AllData`, so you get an error on usage, it's hard to get an error on declaration

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir By usage do you mean run-time?  Because TypeScript will compile all of this down to just `function getAllData(moduleType) { }`.  Either way I'm not seeing any compile *or* runtime errors.

Comment: I get this error `Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'TransientDataMap'` on `trn: TransientDataMap[T];` with ts 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to force an interface to have members. You will get an error on the usage of the interface if it does not conform in some way. And in your example you do get an error if `table` is undefined, it's just that its in the `AllData` interface and it's not a very readable error.

Depending on how important this is to you there are some steps you can take to ensure that you get a legible error close to the declaration site:

**Add a dummy variable assignment**

```
interface TransientDataMap {
    "image": ImageTransientData;
    "text": TextTransientData;
}
// If you get an error typescript here check the interface above
let transientDataMapGuard : {[m in ModuleType]: any } = <TransientDataMap> {};
```

**Use a helper function in defining the interface**

```
// Dummy type helper
function extendsModule<I extends  { [m in ModuleType]: any }>(): I{
    return null as any;
}
// This will cause an error if you don't have all the memebers
let transientDataMapDeclarationHelper =  (extendsModule<{
    "image": ImageTransientData;
    "text": TextTransientData;
}>());

type TransientDataMap = typeof transientDataMapDeclarationHelper;
```

Comment: Still not seeing the error (I'm on TypeScript 2.6.2) but the dummy assignment will deff work.  Thanks!